# "How can I use Bloc to fetch and continuously display data from Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?"

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream, bloc, clean-architecture

i have a food mobile application and i am trying to make the admin portal where i am submiting the meal based on the days and i can also delete each meal seperately by searching for the meal id and then remove it from the firebase real time.

my main requirements are:

1. i want the data submitted or deleted or changed to be automatically detected when i have to display the data in the firebase database real time
2. i don't want to keep rebuilding the user interface and fetch the data again and again if there is no change in the data
3. i want to display the data in a list in a real time so the user wont have to refresh the page cuz the data will be up to date
4. based on the below data the data should be displayed based on the days
   so display sunday meals when it is sunday which is sunday in the data is 0 and monday is 1 and so on which is only five days
5. handle when the data is empty so it tells the user there is no data available yet

```
{
  "schedule_management": {
    "ksc": [
      {
        "-NP6jW5MHaiAlO3eeN9U": "chicken",
        "-NPBjOZytWYAS7NPZ5l3": "kozi",
      },
      {
        "-NP3ioRpMIAdcA8BAiXo": "shla"
      },
      {
        "-NP3htngC3sn1W7dw3lE": "hummus",
        "-NP3ipEQzZQgAvMS7gha": "meat",
        "-NPBnCO1m0zh7W0wS-IT": "chicken"
      },
      {
        "-NP3hwT9kwns5pgfkOrQ": "tomato",
        "-NP3iq14Q7WqixJy3gex": "onion"
      },
      {
        "-NP3hvbOBOr-OG49YKbI": "jalabino",
        "-NP3iqw6BigxhM6ZM5JG": "panana"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the main issue i am facing is i am trying to fetch the data and display it in the real time using stream here is the code below will explain my issue:

```
abstract class ScheduleManagementDataSource {
  Stream<Either<FirebaseFailure, Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllMeals();
  Future<Either<FirebaseFailure, Unit>> deleteMeal(String mealId, int dayIndex);
  Future<Either<FirebaseFailure, Unit>> addMeal(String meal, int dayIndex);
}

class ScheduleManagementDataSourceImpl implements ScheduleManagementDataSource {
  DatabaseReference scheduleRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('schedule_management');

  @override
  Future<Either<FirebaseFailure, Unit>> addMeal(
      String meal, int dayIndex) async {
    try {
      var kitchenType = await getUserType();
      DatabaseReference restaurantRef = scheduleRef.child(kitchenType);
      DatabaseReference dayRef = restaurantRef.child('$dayIndex');
      DatabaseReference newMealRef = dayRef.push();
      await newMealRef.set(meal);
      return right(unit);
    } catch (e) {
      return left(FirebaseFailure(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<FirebaseFailure, Unit>> deleteMeal(
      String mealId, int dayIndex) async {
    try {
      var kitchenType = await getUserType();
      await FirebaseDatabase.instance
          .ref()
          .child('schedule_management')
          .child(kitchenType)
          .child('$dayIndex')
          .child(mealId)
          .remove();
      return right(unit);
    } catch (e) {
      return left(FirebaseFailure(message: e.toString()));
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<Either<FirebaseFailure, Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllMeals() async* {
    try {
      var kitchenType = await getUserType();
      DatabaseReference kitchenRef = scheduleRef.child(kitchenType);
      await for (var event in kitchenRef.onValue) {
        if (event.snapshot.value == null) {
          // break the loop if the stream is closed
          break;
        }
        final dataString = json.encode(event.snapshot.value);
        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(dataString);
        // Emit a Right value to the stream
        yield Right(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // If an error occurs before listening to the database, emit a Left value to the stream
      yield Left(FirebaseFailure(message: e.toString()));
    }

    // Add a return statement at the end of the function
    return;
  }

  Future<String> getUserType() async {
    try {
      final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
      final snapshot = await ref.child('users/${currentUser!.uid}').get();

      if (snapshot.exists) {
        final dataString = json.encode(snapshot.value);

        Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(dataString);

        final userEntity = UserModel.fromFirebaseMap(data);
        if (userEntity.uType.isNotEmpty) {
          if (userEntity.uType == 'KSCKitchen') {
            return 'ksc';
          } else if (userEntity.uType == 'AwbaraKitchen') {
            return 'awbara';
          }
        }
      }
      return '';
    } catch (e) {
      throw fb.FirebaseException(message: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

where in the above code the code stops at   `Stream<Either<FirebaseFailure, Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllMeals() async*`   and and i think the issue is it keeps loading the `stream` without stopping
here is my other code while i am using clean arch and bloc

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import '../../../../domain/usecases/get_all_meals_usecase.dart';
import '../../add_delete_meal_bloc/add_delete_meal_bloc.dart';

part 'get_all_meals_event.dart';
part 'get_all_meals_state.dart';
class GetAllMealsBloc extends Bloc<GetAllMealsEvent, GetAllMealsState> {
  final GetAllMealsUsecase getAllMealsUsecase;
  final AddDeleteMealBloc addDeleteMealBloc;
  StreamSubscription? addDeleteMealSubscription;

  GetAllMealsBloc({
    required this.getAllMealsUsecase,
    required this.addDeleteMealBloc,
  }) : super(GetAllMealsInitial()) {
    on<GetAllMealsEvent>((event, emit) async {
      if (event is GetMealsEvent) {
        emit(LoadingGetAllMealsState());

        final stream = getAllMealsUsecase();
        addDeleteMealSubscription?.cancel();
        addDeleteMealSubscription = addDeleteMealBloc.stream.listen((state) {
          if (state is MessageAddDeleteMealState) {
            add(GetMealsEvent());
          }
        });
        stream.listen((either) {
          final state = either.fold(
            (failure) => ErrorGetAllMealsState(message: failure.message),
            (meals) => LoadedGetAllMealsState(meals: meals),
          );
          emit(state);
        }, onError: (e) {
          emit(ErrorGetAllMealsState(message: e.toString()));
        });
      }
    });
  }@override
  Future<void> close() {
    addDeleteMealSubscription?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

```
part of 'get_all_meals_bloc.dart';


abstract class GetAllMealsEvent extends Equatable {
  const GetAllMealsEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class GetMealsEvent extends GetAllMealsEvent {}
```

```
part of 'get_all_meals_bloc.dart';

abstract class GetAllMealsState extends Equatable {
  const GetAllMealsState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class GetAllMealsInitial extends GetAllMealsState {}

class LoadingGetAllMealsState extends GetAllMealsState {}

class LoadedGetAllMealsState extends GetAllMealsState {
  final Map<String, dynamic> meals;

  const LoadedGetAllMealsState({required this.meals});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [meals];
}

class ErrorGetAllMealsState extends GetAllMealsState {
  final String message;

  const ErrorGetAllMealsState({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class MealsUpdatedState extends GetAllMealsState {
  final Map<String, dynamic> meals;

  const MealsUpdatedState({required this.meals});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [meals];
}
```

this is the user interface:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:iq_project/features/Kitchen/schedule_management/presentation/logic/get_all_meals_bloc/bloc/get_all_meals_bloc.dart';

import '../../../../../../core/injection/injection_container.dart';

import '../../logic/add_delete_meal_bloc/add_delete_meal_bloc.dart';

class MealsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final selectedDay;

  const MealsList({Key? key, required this.selectedDay}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => sl<GetAllMealsBloc>()..add(GetMealsEvent()),
      child: BlocBuilder<GetAllMealsBloc, GetAllMealsState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is LoadingGetAllMealsState) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (state is ErrorGetAllMealsState) {
            return Center(child: Text(state.message));
          } else if (state is LoadedGetAllMealsState ||
              state is MealsUpdatedState) {
            final meals = state is LoadedGetAllMealsState
                ? state.meals
                : (state as MealsUpdatedState).meals;
            return ListView.separated(
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
                height: 1,
                thickness: 0.3,
              ),
              itemCount: meals.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                List<dynamic> mealItems = meals.values.toList();
                String mealId = meals.keys.toList()[index];
                String mealName = mealItems[index].toString();

                return ListTile(
                  leading: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                    child: Text(
                      "${index + 1} -",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await sl<AddDeleteMealBloc>()
                          .deleteMealUsecase(mealId, selectedDay);
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    mealName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: Text('No meals found!'));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this was for submit and delete:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:dartz/dartz.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import '../../../../../../core/error/failure.dart';
import '../../../../../../core/error/firebase_exceptions.dart';
import '../../../domain/usecases/add_meal_usecase.dart';
import '../../../domain/usecases/delete_meal_usecase.dart';

part 'add_delete_meal_event.dart';
part 'add_delete_meal_state.dart';

class AddDeleteMealBloc extends Bloc<AddDeleteMealEvent, AddDeleteMealState> {
  final AddMealUsecase addMealUsecase;
  final DeleteMealUsecase deleteMealUsecase;

  AddDeleteMealBloc(
      {required this.addMealUsecase, required this.deleteMealUsecase})
      : super(AddDeleteMealInitial());

  @override
  Stream<AddDeleteMealState> mapEventToState(AddDeleteMealEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AddMealEvent) {
      yield const LoadingAddDeleteMealState(isLoading: true);
      try {
        final failureOrDoneMessage =
            await addMealUsecase(event.meal, event.dayIndex);

        yield _eitherDoneMessageOrErrorState(
          failureOrDoneMessage,
          'Meal added successfully.',
        );
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        yield ErrorAddDeleteMealState(message: e.message);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ErrorAddDeleteMealState(message: 'An unknown error occurred.');
      }
    } else if (event is DeleteMealEvent) {
      yield const LoadingAddDeleteMealState(isLoading: true);
      try {
        final failureOrDoneMessage =
            await deleteMealUsecase(event.mealId, event.dayIndex);

        yield _eitherDoneMessageOrErrorState(
          failureOrDoneMessage,
          "Meal deleted successfully.",
        );
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        yield ErrorAddDeleteMealState(message: e.message);
      } catch (_) {
        yield ErrorAddDeleteMealState(message: 'An unknown error occurred.');
      }
    }
  }

  AddDeleteMealState _eitherDoneMessageOrErrorState(
      Either<FirebaseFailure, Unit> either, String message) {
    return either.fold(
      (failure) => ErrorAddDeleteMealState(
        message: failure.message,
      ),
      (_) => MessageAddDeleteMealState(
        message: message,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
part of 'add_delete_meal_bloc.dart';

abstract class AddDeleteMealEvent extends Equatable {
  const AddDeleteMealEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddMealEvent extends AddDeleteMealEvent {
  final String meal;
  final int dayIndex;

  AddMealEvent({required this.meal, required this.dayIndex});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [meal, dayIndex];
}

class DeleteMealEvent extends AddDeleteMealEvent {
  final String mealId;
  final int dayIndex;

  DeleteMealEvent({required this.mealId, required this.dayIndex});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [mealId, dayIndex];
}
```

```
part of 'add_delete_meal_bloc.dart';

abstract class AddDeleteMealState extends Equatable {
  const AddDeleteMealState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AddDeleteMealInitial extends AddDeleteMealState {}

class LoadingAddDeleteMealState extends AddDeleteMealState {
  final bool isLoading;

  const LoadingAddDeleteMealState({required this.isLoading});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [isLoading];
}

class LoadedAddDeleteMealState extends AddDeleteMealState {
  final Map<String, dynamic> meals;

  LoadedAddDeleteMealState({required this.meals});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [meals];
} 

class ErrorAddDeleteMealState extends AddDeleteMealState {
  final String message;

  ErrorAddDeleteMealState({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}

class MessageAddDeleteMealState extends AddDeleteMealState {
  final String message;

  MessageAddDeleteMealState({required this.message});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [message];
}
```

i am excpecting to meet the requirments but i dont know why it stops in stream where i have tried to use await and subscription as well but i don't understand it
can you please help with these requirments:

1. i want the data submitted or deleted or changed to be automatically detected when i have to display the data in the firebase database real time
2. i don't want to keep rebuilding the user interface and fetch the data again and again if there is no change in the data
3. i want to display the data in a list in a real time so the user wont have to refresh the page cuz the data will be up to date
4. based on the below data the data should be displayed based on the days
   so display sunday meals when it is sunday which is sunday in the data is 0 and monday is 1 and so on which is only five days
5. handle when the data is empty so it tells the user there is no data available yet

Comment: Sorry, but your question is way too long and involved, which makes it very unlikely that somebody will answer. I recommend reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then focusing on [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Both of these will increase the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).